# Cursor moves after endqoute in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cursor

Whenever I type double quotes, the cursor moves outside to the right of the end quote. It is extremely annoying. I cannot find an appropriate setting to control this behaviour either.

Is there a setting to control the cursor behaviour when typing quotes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you will probably have to disable double-quote autocompletion. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253814/how-to-turn-off-double-quotes-auto-completion-in-visual-studio-2019-for-c-edit

personally, I always find that IDEs either do too little to help me with quotes, or do too much, but never find the sweet spot. Many years ago i got in the habit of typing both quotes at once, followed by the left arrow, just to make sure I always have the right number of quotes for a complex expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you asking what I think your asking then do the following.

Go to your settings and then type in the filter:

```
Auto Closing Overtype
```

Its probably either on: **auto** or **always**. Change this to **never**. It should work now (it did for me)

Comment: Thank you. this worked.